# Cookie returns NaN with parseInt

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

When I am trying to get the Cookie "Gold" which is a currency for my game, it returns NaN. right now the cookie is named "gold" and has a value of 7238 (for me obviously as I saved that as a cookie on my comp)

```
function getCookie(cname){
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i= 0; i < ca.length; i++){
        var c = ca[i];
        while(c.charAt(0) == ' '){
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if(c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

var gold;
function getGold() {
    if(getCookie("gold") == null) {
        gold = 0;
    } else {
        var sup = getCookie("gold");
        var co = parseInt(sup, 10);
        gold += co;
    }
}
getGold();
```

This results is NaN which is not helping as it isn't saying where I went wrong, I can also give the function I use to save cookies which is as followed:

```
function saveCookies(cname, value) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (365 * 24 * 60 * 60 *1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + value + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}
```

Then when some hooligan clicks the "Save" button one of the functions it performs is

```
saveCookies("gold", gold")
```

That concludes all the information I could possibly give unless you need the whole program, which can be located at matrix-hub.com/CodeCoins.php

Comment: What is `sup` set to before `parseInt`?

Comment: How did you verify the value? What's `console.log(sup)` ?

Comment: Also why are you using cookies instead of localstorage? And why are you storing it locally at all if hooligans can change it?

Comment: what is the value of `getCookie("gold");` before you parseInt on it? That is potentially the only piece of information needed here

Comment: what is your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This results is NaN which is not helping as it isn't saying where I went wrong**

First of all change this line `saveCookies("gold", gold")` to `saveCookies("gold",7238)` here your first argument is cookie **name** that is gold and second one is cookie **value** that should be 7238 **not** "gold"

Secondly, when you set `var gold;` the value of gold is `undefined`. So in your code block when you go to the `else` block because `getCookie("gold") == null` condition is `false`, value of **gold** is still `undefined`

```
var gold;
function getGold() {
    if(getCookie("gold") == null) {
        gold = 0;
    } else {
        var sup = getCookie("gold");
        var co = parseInt(sup, 10);  //7238
        // this is where you messed up, undefined = undefined + 7238
        gold += co;   
    }
   return gold; // also missed this return line
}
console.log(getGold()); // it is returning NaN
```

Actually with this line `gold += co;` what do you want to accomplish ? 
if you set cookie value **gold=7238** then this line `gold += co;` should return `14476`?

Comment: You are amazing! I forgot to set gold to a temporary value, then I forgot return gold, thank you so much and nice eye

Comment: @InsanityMatrix glad it solves your problem. Best of luck :)